# How to make React Router render NotFound when there is nothing to display?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, router

I am building a blog with React Router. After fetching blogposts I am paginating the results onto the page: *localhost:8080/category/general/4*

I this case, I am on the last page of results. Lets say someone goes to *localhost:8080/category/general/5* and there is no posts returned from Pagination to be displayed.

Expected behaviour: NotFound component is rendered.
Actual behaviour: Category page gets rendered with no blog posts.

How do I let React know that certain page doesn't exist since the information about number of pages is sitting in Pagination component?

Routes in App.js:

```
<Switch>
    <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home/1" />
    <Route path="/home/:page?" component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/category/:category/:page?" component={CategoryPage} />
    <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
</Switch>
```

Pagination.js

```
const Pagination = (props) => {
    const { page = 1 } = useParams();
    const {
        children, path, limit = 5,
    } = props;
    const begin = limit * (page - 1);
    const end = limit * page;

    const pagesTotal = Math.ceil(children.length / limit);

    const links = new Array(pagesTotal).fill(0).map((link, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
            <Link to={`${path}${index + 1}`}>{index + 1}</Link>
        </li>
    ));

    return (
        <div>
            {children.slice(begin, end)}
            <ul className="pagination-links--container">{links}</ul>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

handle it in CategoryPage

```
props.match.page < maxPageNumber? <regularPage />: <NotFoundPage/>
```